# How do I Disable a button with an image without reducing the alpha in obejective C?

Tags: objective-c, image, button, alpha

After creating a round rect button, i disabled the button and the alpha of the button stays at 1 unless i reduced the alpha to 0.5 manually. But after inserting an image to the button, the alpha of the button would be set to 0.5 automatically even after setting the alpha to 1 after disabling the button.

I would like to disable the button containing an image without affecting it's alpha.

Can anyone Help me?

Regards,

Bob

Comment: If you disable a button you should change its appearance so the user isn't confused when they try to tap it and it doesn't work. But if you really want to disable it, you can set the userInteractionEnabled property to no. But I would have to ask, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Oh, I'm actually creating a "Memory Game", some sort like the "Memory Game" played with cards. Therefore I Do not want the user to be able to open the same "card" while being able to see the image of whatever he have chosen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at the `UIButton`'s [`adjustsImageWhenDisabled`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815-CH3-SW22) property. Setting that to NO should do what you want.

There's also a similar property for highlighted buttons.

Answer (score 0):

When no image is set for the disabled state, the system may generate one by modifying the normal state image.  To prevent that, set the same image for normal and UIControlStateDisabled.  Either use:

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state;
```

Or set it in the xib.

Answer (score 0):

yea the  adjustsImageWhenDisabled property and setting it to NO is the way.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for posting, Cheesebunz but you could have just left a comment on that answer instead of posting a new answer. lol =D